# Google Maps Utility Library v3 - Infoboxes not closing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Infobox from the Google Maps Utility Library V3 and I'm having a bit of trouble removing all Infoboxes in one go without keeping track of all the infoboxes or adding an event listen.

I'm currently using the following code.

```
function initMarkers(map, markerData) {


    for(var i=0; i<markerData.length; i++) {

    var iconimage = "markers/" + trackall + ".png";
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: false,
            position: markerData[i].latLng,
            visible: true,
            icon: iconimage
        }),
        boxText = document.createElement("div"),
        //these are the options for all infoboxes
        infoboxOptions = {

         content: boxText
        ,disableAutoPan: true
        ,maxWidth: 0
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(20, -75)
        ,zIndex: null
        ,boxStyle: {
          background: "url('') no-repeat"
          ,opacity: 0.75
          ,width: "140px"
         }
        ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
        ,closeBoxURL: ""
        ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        ,isHidden: false
        ,pane: "floatPane"
        ,enableEventPropagation: false
    };

        newMarkers.push(marker);
        //define the text and style for all infoboxes
        boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 5px; background: #E0E7EF; padding: 5px;";
        boxText.innerHTML = markerData[i].address + "<br>" + markerData[i].state;
        //Define the infobox

        newMarkers[i].infobox = new InfoBox(infoboxOptions);
        //Open box when page is loaded

        newMarkers[i].infobox.open(map, marker);

        //Add event listen, so infobox for marker is opened when user clicks on it.  Notice the return inside the anonymous function - this creates
        //a closure, thereby saving the state of the loop variable i for the new marker.  If we did not return the value from the inner function,
        //the variable i in the anonymous function would always refer to the last i used, i.e., the last infobox. This pattern (or something that
        //serves the same purpose) is often needed when setting function callbacks inside a for-loop.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                //newMarkers[i].infobox.open(map, this);
                //map.panTo(markerData[i].latLng);
                //newMarkers[i].infobox.close();
            /}
        })(marker, i));
    }

    return newMarkers;

}

//here the call to initMarkers() is made with the necessary data for each marker.  All markers are then returned as an array into the markers variable
markers = initMarkers(map, [
    { latLng: pointall}

]);
```

In the above example I'm using the variable pointall which contains the ever changing marker information.  The site is a flight tracking site so it tracks any number of aircraft at different locations constantly.   Every time there's an update eg. new markers to plot, I use the following function to remove the old markers first.

```
function clearOverlays() {
  if (newMarkers) {
    for (var i = 0; i < newMarkers.length; i++ ) {
    newMarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}
```

The above removes all the markers but if I add

```
newMarkers[i].infobox.close();
```

It deletes the first marker but stops executing code.

Is there an easy way of just saying.. Close all open Infoboxes.  I don't need to know which is which as they will all need to be closed.  Currently the infoboxes are opened with the new marker but the old infobox is staying.

Note: I'm not advanced with javascript so be easy on me ;)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Edit:  I'm not having much luck here.   As suggested I've tried creating an array to hold the Infoboxes but I must be doing something wrong.

I've tried adding the following declaration:

```
ibArray = [];
```

I've then tried adding :

```
ibArray.push(marker);
```

I've added the above in several locations including immediately after pushing the marker into the newMarkers array but no matter where I place the code It's breaking the rest of my code and not displaying any infoboxes.

I suspect I've got the syntax incorrect, and I also can't work out where to place the code.

Can anyone else help?

Answer (score 1):

You should do the same you're doing for the markers, ie keep track of the infoWindows and loop through the array, closing them (and removing them from the array).

Comment: oh ok.. so there's no easy way to just close all in one go without keeping track of them?  I guess I'll just try and work out how to keep track of them I guess.  Bit of a pain though.  It would have been nice to be able to just close all in one go without iterating.

Comment: Not that I know of. I am writing a small helper library to deal with such issues in GMaps. And this is exactly what I am doing: keep a record of all markers and infowindows created, so that I can close them (or else) easily.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'll experiment further as I'm not entirely sure how to keep track of the Infoboxes with my current code.  I'll play around further.  Thanks heaps.